# How do I conditional format border colour of shape based on cell values in Excel?

Tags: excel

This is my first post on here so go easy.

After using paste linked picture with a conditionally formatted cell, I feel that it doesn't do what I need. Therefore I am trying to format border colours based on cell values but I don't believe I can do this without using VBA, which I have no clue how to use. I want to apply the same conditional formatting rules in the screenshot to the shape border if possible.

Can someone help me out please?

[Worksheet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8uWE.jpg)

Comment: I can see from you public profile that you have not taken the [tour](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tour) yes. I suggest you do so and read the following: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why is help me not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question), then come back and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52823188/edit), showing us what you've tried so far and how it's not giving you the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible (without VBS) to change the thickness of the borders.

But changing the style is possible by editing the rule > click on format > click on border tab and edit your preferred border style.

[Hope this is what you meant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aix1x.jpg) (Only in german unfortunately)